# Cannot extract text with preg_match

Tags: php, preg-match

I have this code:

```
include('class.pdf2text.php');
$a = new PDF2Text();
$a->setFilename('557270281.pdf');  
$a->decodePDF();

preg_match('/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}/', $a->output(), $date);
print_r($date);

preg_match('/bre(.*?)Pro/', $a->output(), $nombre);
print_r($nombre);
```

I can extract the `$date` but not the `$nombre`, as it gets empty result.
I tested the second regex in my code at http://gskinner.com/RegExr/, and it works.

If I add this to my code,

```
$n ="Nombre : john smith angola Provincia : MADRID ";
```

and then change the the second regex in my code to,

```
preg_match('/bre(.*?)Pro/', $n, $nombre);
```

it works.

How can I extract it from `$a->output()`?

Comment: do `echo $a->output();` in above and show us the result.

Comment: i cant show you the echo... but you can try yourself with any pdf file, using the class above.

Comment: I can, but I won't get the string you're dealing with;)

Comment: yeah, but its private info.. and i dont want to expose it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tfe [`/s` modifier](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) is there to make the `.` match newlines:

```
preg_match('/bre(.*?)Pro/s', $a->output(), $nombre);
```